# Averaging Categorical Estimators: How do I optimally average three or more categorical predictions?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, optimization, parameter-estimation

Example:
Three analysts predict the likelihood of winners between Superman, Thor, and Wonder Woman in a series of three-way mathematical trivia competitions.

- Analyst A predicts the probability of victory for each superhero
  $(p_s, p_t, p_w)$ in the next competition is $(p_{s_A}, p_{t_A},
     p_{w_A})$.
- Analyst B predicts the probability of victory in the next
  competition is $(p_{s_B}, p_{t_B}, p_{w_B})$.
- Analyst C predicts the
  probability of victory in the next competition is $(p_{s_C}, p_{t_C},
     p_{w_C})$.

I know one analyst is more accurate than the others, so I could simply create an ad-hoc weighting that emphasizes that person's prediction. In fact, I know each person's historical predictions and the final outcome, so I feel like I should be able to do much better than an ad-hoc weighting. However, I am not certain how to weight the predictions optimally using that historical data.

> Side Note: If it was a continuous prediction of a single parameter ($x$) and there were only two estimators (A and B), I know I would simply do a reciprocal-variance-weighted average:
>
> $$\mu(x_A, x_B) = \frac{\sigma_B^2 x_A + \sigma_A^2 x_B}{ \sigma_A^2 + \sigma_B^2 }$$

I am new to working with categorical data.

Comment: This sounds a bit like the problem of [hypothesis boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boosting_(machine_learning)) in machine learning. In order to apply those ideas you would need a clear notion of "loss", that is, what are you actually trying to maximize/minimize?

Comment: @JackM, I think you are right. It does feel machine learning-y. Again, I am not familiar with categorical data analysis like this. I briefly skimmed the Wiki page you linked, then it seemed like I should follow up by reading the [AdaBoost wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost#Example_algorithm_(Discrete_AdaBoost)) and then I watched this ["AdaBoost, Clearly Explained"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsK-xG1cLYA) video, but I don't feel like I am any closer to knowing what to do next. Should I be summing the historical "exponential loss" (huh?) by analyst? If so, then what?

Comment: Analogous to my "side note," should I just create a "variance" based on the distance between each analyst's historical probability vectors, $(p_s, p_t, p_w)$, and the actual historical outcome (e.g., if Wonder Woman won the first contest, then the actual historical outcome for that contest would be (0, 0, 1))? Then should I just weight each analyst's prediction by the sum of the "variances" from the other analysts?

Comment: In order to decide what the best strategy is you have to define what you're trying to do. How do you, a priori, define "best strategy"? What quantity would the best strategy maximize or minimize?

Comment: @Jack, I think I see what you are getting at. I guess I just want to minimize the error of my estimates. Basically, I want to do the closest thing to a linear regression on a two-dimensional data set, but I want to do it for every trivia competition between the superheroes based on my analysts's prior predictions and the outcomes of prior competitions.

Comment: But what is the error of an estimate? If I estimate $(\frac13,\frac56,\frac16)$, and then Superman wins, what's my error?

Comment: @Jack, those probabilities do not sum to 1, but assuming they did. I would assume the error would simply be $1-p_s$, so $1-\frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}$ in your case. Do you have a different method of determining error that you think would make more sense in this case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117037/discussion-between-tmo-and-jack-m).